# error in application in the terminal using keras

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu, keras

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer 
ImportError: No module named keras.preprocessing.text

Any solution?
thank you

my operating system: Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: Have you tried installing the module somehow?

Comment: Using TensorFlow backend.
Illegal instruction (core dumped)

Now I get this error, any other solution?
I tried to downgrade the tensorflow 1.5 but without success.

Comment: I was successful, I used the conda install tensorflow-gpu -n tensorflow.

Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade your keras package to latest version with command

pip install -U pip keras tensorflow

Comment: Using TensorFlow backend.
Illegal instruction (core dumped)

Now I get this error, any other solution?
I tried to downgrade the tensorflow 1.5 but without success.

Comment: I was successful, I used the conda install tensorflow-gpu -n tensorflow.

Thank you for your support!